# Iterating through parent entity to return array of child entities

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I am trying to build an array of entities from a server query that exist in an object arrays

The diagram below illustrates my model:

[image: Entity model]

In my datacontext, I've applied the following code:

```
function getByDboardConfig(dboardConfig) {
        var busUnitDims = [];
        var busUnitsTotalCount = dboardConfig.busUnits.length;
        var buCount = 0;

        dboardConfig.busUnits.forEach(function (busUnit) {
            eq.from('BusUnitDimensions') // eq = breeze.EntityQuery
                .where('busUnitId', '==', busUnit.id)
                .using(em).execute() // em = EntityManager
                .to$q(succeeded, failed); // using Angular, thus to$q
        });

        function succeeded(data) {
            buCount++;
            data.results.forEach(function (result) {
                busUnitDims.push(result);
            });

            if (buCount === busUnitsTotalCount) {
                console.log(busUnits.length);  
                return busUnitDims;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I log to the console as show the length of the array, I get the correct entity count, but when I return the result of this call to my controller I get undefined. Not understanding why?

I've tried returning `$q.when(busUnitDims)` as well but I still get undefined.

Comment: I'm hypothesising that I'm somehow not returning a promise. Could this be?

Comment: Your getByDboardConfig() function is not returning anything at all? (Notice that the value succeeded return never gets propagated to your controller, as it's one scope below).

Comment: @SveinT Thanks for your comment. Yes, I've noticed that if I add `return busUnitDims` outside the succeeded function's scope, my controller does get the return, but sometimes it returns 0 results, sometimes the result after forEach iteration 1 and sometimes the result after iteration 2. Can you offer any enhancements to make this more stable?

Comment: If you want to return the actual object and not a promise for it than you must ensure all promises are resolved before returning. And you do need to actually return a value from getByDboardConfig - you are not doing that at the moment. You could create an array of promises with forEach and only return after $q.all(promisesArray) is resolved.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to console.log(busUnitDims.length) instead of console.log(busUnits.length)? Pls check the result then reply to me

Comment: @AdelSal Apologies, that was just a typo in the SO code snippet. I am logging `busUnitDims.length` and it returns the correct value

Comment: @daveb73 That's fine.. Please check my answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the function is not returning anything, even if you relocate the return line outside the succeeded block
, it may return before filling the array is finished(notice you're executing the query asynchronously )

Neverthless, looking at your code; I take it you are getting the `busUints` and then query for each of their line items `BusUnitDimensions` separately; 
that could mean many roundtrips to the server.

Anyways, you aim to fetching `busUnits` along with their related `BusUnitDimensions` (**eager loading**).

Although you didn't provide an idea of how your view model or your controller looks like; I assume you have one view for `DboardConfig` and another view for both related `busUnits` and `BusUnitDimensions`

so your workflow is:

1. Get a list of DboardConfigs
2. for each `DboardConfig`, load it's `busUnits` along with `BusUnitDimensions`

Hence, your function could be :

```
function getByDboardConfig(dboardConfig) {
   return  eq.from("busUnits")
    .where("dboardConfigId", "==", dboardConfig.id)
    .expand("BusUnitDimensions")
    .using(em).execute() // em = EntityManager
```

Then inside your controller:

```
   $Scope.getBusUnitsandDimentions = function () {
    dataservice.getByDboardConfig($Scope.dboardConfig)
        .then(succeeded)
        .fail(failed);
};

    function succeeded(data) {
       $Scope.busUnits = [];
        data.results.forEach(function (result) {
            $Scope.busUnits.push(result);
        });
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can remove the coding for  fetching `busUnits` since we've already fetched it with it's related child table.

Simply put:

1. `busUnits` to get your array of bus units for a specified `DboardConfig`
2. `busUnits.BusUnitDimensions` to get it's related dimensions

Comment: Thanks. Give me a chance to study this in the context of my application and I'll give you some feedback thereafter.

Comment: you're welcome. Please take a look at Breeze documentation in case you're planning to enhance it with caching http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in also taking a look at [***this question***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679073/entity-framework-object-graph-deletion-with-breeze), which deals with deleting object graphs. I've read elsewhere that Breeze doesn't support cascaded deletes, but if you read my question, you'll notice some strange observations.

Comment: That's my friend, is another issue..Anyway, I've answered that too.:)