# Entity Framework object graph deletion with Breeze

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, cascading-deletes

I am encountering a recurring problem that just makes no sense, and hoping someone (in the Breeze team?) can shed some light.

The following model illustrates the entities in question.

[image]

As you can see, I'm adhering pretty strictly to Entity Framework conventions in my property names, and as a result, if I check in SQL the cascade on delete rules are set by EF code first when it creates the db.

Now, when I try to delete a `BusUnit` manually in SQL, the delete cascades correctly and the corresponding `BusUnitDimensions` are also deleted, as it should be. Likewise, if I delete a `Dimension` in SQL, the corresponding `BusUnitDimensions` are also deleted.

However, in my application, if I mark a `BusUnit` as `setDeleted` with Breeze and then try `saveChanges`, I get the following error.

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one
or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is
made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null
value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

Strangely though, if I mark a `Dimension` for deletion and then save (within Breeze), the cascaded delete works correctly and both the `Dimension` and its corresponding `BusUnitDimensions` are deleted.

So, why the inconsistency? Why are the cascaded delete rules in SQL not being applied for `BusUnits` but yet they're working for `Dimensions`? I've read elsewhere that Breeze does not support cascaded deletes, but then why is my `Dimensions` case working?

---

EDIT:

I've removed my previous edits as they weren't relevant. The changes below follow on from Ward's answer...

My model now looks like this, and `BusUnitDims` now uses `BusUnitId` and `DimId` as a compound key, and I've added a `bool`, `IsBud` for the purposes of payload.

[image]

I haven't yet implemented deletes for BusUnits, but already if I try delete a Dim, I'm getting the same error message:

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one
or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is
made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null
value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

I have noticed that cascaded deletes is no longer enabled, and in fact, to get EF to build the database I to add the following configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BusUnitDim>()
    .HasRequired(bud => bud.BusUnit)
        .WithMany(bu => bu.BusUnitDims)
        .HasForeignKey(bud => bud.BusUnitId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<BusUnitDim>()
    .HasRequired(bud => bud.Dim)
        .WithMany(d => d.BusUnitDims)
        .HasForeignKey(bud => bud.DimId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

So, with cascading now explicitly not in place, I can understand why the error occurs. Does that imply that in the controller, one has to specifically mark each map for deletion when deleting a parent Dim or BusUnit and before saveChanges is called, or is there some way to configure EF to take advantage of cascaded deletes as this would hugely simplify the code in my controller?

(PS: it gets even more complex, because `BusUnitDims` ends up having a further join table of its own, `MetricBusUnitDims` to accommodate yet another entity in the model and their relationships. This is why I'm trying to get the principles right early on)

---

EDIT: (A CONTROLLER SOLUTION FOR BUSUNITS)

So, the following approach works for `BusUnits`:

```
function deleteBusUnit(busUnitVm) { // note that you pass in the item viewmodel, not the entity
    var busUnit = busUnitVm.busUnit;
    var mapVms = busUnitVm.dimMapVms;
    var dimHash = createBusUnitDimHash(busUnit);

    mapVms.forEach(function (mapVm) {
        var map = dimHash[mapVm.dim.id];
        if (map) {
            datacontext.markDeleted(map);
        }
    });
    datacontext.markDeleted(busUnit);
    save().then(function() { getDBoardConfig(); });
    }
}
```

Is this the correct approach? if so, I'll still have to figure out the following:

- How to approach `Dims`. These are different becuase the item viewmodel is defined for BusUnits.
- How to approach the situation where there is a join tabel one level down, e.g. `MetricBusUnitDIm`.

---

EDIT: (A CONTROLLER SOLUTION FOR DIMS)

```
function deleteDim(dim) {
    return bsDialog.deleteDialog(dim.name, true)
        .then(function () {
            vm.busUnitVms.forEach(function (busUnitVm) {
                busUnitVm.busUnit.busUnitDims.forEach(function (bud) {
                    if (bud.dimId === dim.id) {
                        datacontext.markDeleted(bud);
                    }
                });
            });
            datacontext.markDeleted(dim);
            save().then(function () { getDboardConfig(); });
        });
}
```

Comment: Specifically asking a user for help on a question is generally shunned upon - just thinking out load but if you are looking for specific support from individuals have you considered paid support?

Comment: @PWKad Thanks. Relatively new to SO, so apologies if I contravened an unwritten etiquette. I am currently in discussions with the company concerned, but our time difference makes momentum slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problems are traceable to the fact that your mapping table `BusUnitDimension` has its own primary key, `Id`, as opposed to the more typical approach in which the `BusUnitId` and `DimensionId` FK properties together comprise the compound primary key of `BusUnitDimension`.

> Observe that `OrderDetails` in Northwind and the `HeroPoweMap` in the Breeze many-to-many example have compound keys.

Your choice creates complications.

First, it becomes possible to create multiple `BusUnitDimension` entities representing the same association between `BusUnit` and `Dimension` (i.e., they all have the same pair of FKs). The database may be able to prevent this (it's been a long time since I looked) but whether it does or doesn't, it won't prevent you from creating those duplicates in Breeze ... and maybe not in EF either.

Secondly, it opens you up to the problem you're currently facing. If those mapping entities are in the `DbContext` when you perform the delete, EF may (apparently does) try to null their FK properties as it sets either `BusUnit` or `Dimension` to the deleted state.

You can get around this, as has been suggested, by making both the `BusUnitId` and `DimensionId` FK properties nullable. But that is contrary to the semantics as a `BusUnitDimension` must link a real `BusUnit` to a real `Dimension`; they aren't optional. The practical consequence may be that you don't get cascade delete from the EF perspective if you do this (not sure if the DB will enforce that either). That means you'd have orphaned `BusUnitDimension` rows in your database with one or both FKs being null. I speculate because I'm not used to getting into this kind of trouble.

Another approach would be to set their FK values to zero (I think Breeze does this for you). Of course this implies the existence of `BusUnit` and `Dimension` table rows with `Id == 0`, if only during the delete operation.

> Btw, you could actually have such  "sentinel entities" in your DB.

You must make sure that these `BusUnitDimension` are in the deleted state or EF (and the DB) will either reject them (referential integrity constraint) or orphan them (you'll have `BusUnitDimension` rows in your database with one or both FKs being zero).

Alternatively, if you know that the DB will cascade delete them, you can simply remove them from the `DbContext` (remove from the `EntityInfoMap` in the `EFContextProvider`). But now you have to tell the Breeze client to get rid of them too if it happens to have them hanging around.

### Enough Already!

These wandering thoughts should tell you that you've got yourself in a jam here with way too much bookkeeping ... and all because you gave `BusUnitDimension` its own `Id` primary key.

It gets a lot easier if you give `BusUnitDimension` the compound key, {`BusUnitId`, `DimensionId`}. You must also give it a payload property (anything will do) to prevent EF from hiding it in its "many-to-many" implementation because Breeze doesn't handle that. Adding any nonsense property will do the trick.

HTH

Comment: @AdelSal Ward, thank you as always for a comprehensive reply. I am busy going through some housekeeping on my code as a result of this problem and it's ended up being a good thing as I've cleaned up many other minor issues along the way. i'll be sure to implement your advice and i'll post any issues I encounter in the interests of those who might be interested. Once I've solved this debacle, I think I'll have some nice content for a blog on the topic :-)

Comment: Ok, I've implemented this recommendation as I understand it, but I'm still getting that horrid message when trying to delete a parent entity, so clearly I'm still doing something wrong. I'll post some extra content as an edit.

Comment: I now have deletions on both sides of the many-many working, and for those interested, I've added an edit for the second side as its slightly different if you don't want the EF errors. I must say though (after this experience) that breeze's lack of native support for EF many-many relationships introduces much complexity. In my case, for example, if I want to delete a `dboardConfig`, i'm going to need to add controller logic that first deals with `busUnits and `dims`. And if I add more entities, I'll need to revisit again. imho, this is something that needs to be handled by breeze.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with Breeze.. The originating message is from Entity Framework..
inside `BusUnitDimension` Model update `BusUnitId` property to:

```
 public Nullable<int> BusUnitId { get; set; }
```

Notice the Nullable struct..

Comment: Hi. This was my first instinct too, but I cannot understand why the cascased delete works for one side of the 1-m-1 when deleting the parent entity, but not for the other side. Anyways, your proposed solution doesn't work unfortunately because now, when deleting a `BusUnit`, the `BusUnitId` in the `BusUnitDimensions` table is just nulled. The result I'm looking for is that every entry in `BusUnitDimensions` where `BusUnitId` = `BusUnit.Id` in the `BusUnits` table should be deleted whenever a selected `BusUnit` is deleted.

Comment: If you're having cascaded delete enabled in the database. That should do the trick. I've been into this before and that's what works for me. Please consider adding more details in your question(eg. model classes, client side delete commands) if you want it to get solved.

Comment: btw, if you applied my answer to your previous question. Deleting BusUnit in the client side should clear it's child collections too

Comment: I will add further info as an additional edit. Your previous advice unfortunately did not delete children. If you are interested in looking into this in depth, please email me (see my profile), and perhaps we can have a quick pair-programming session online. I am always keen to work with others and share my approaches.

Comment: sure, but emails in SO are set to private.

Comment: not sure how to share then, can I do this in a comment or does it contravene any SO rules? Perhaps contact me via my website?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Seems we'll have to wait and see if anyone else has light to shed on why EF is not acting as expected :)